# Tracert shows unlisted IP adress. Can't ping or tracert in LAN

Tags: windows, networking, ping, traceroute, icmp

So this issue is boggling my mind right now.

I have the following setup:

device *A* - my desktop computer, Win 7, wired ethernet connection to router (Fritzbox 7490).

device *B* - my laptop computer, win 8.1, WLAN.

Both are on the same subnet and ip range 192.168.178.x

a cannot ping b. b however can ping a.

The following measures were tested already:

- allowing ICMP v4 on both ends. No result.
- turning off firewall on both ends. No result

tracert from a to b first only resulted in request timeouts.

A few minutes later tracert showed an unkown ip adress:

 `1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  fritz.box [192.168.178.1]
 2    21 ms    22 ms    21 ms  87.186.224.35 <--- this one
 3     *        *        *     Zeitüberschreitung der Anforderung.
 4  ^C`

I couldn't ping that adress directly. Request timeout.

Neither my router interface nor `ipconfig /all` on *A* or *B* listed that IP adress.

This is the [whois [who.is]](https://who.is/whois-ip/ip-address/87.186.224.35) for that address.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Ok sorry for not making things clear enough. I want to establish a connection between the devices and found out my desktop cant even ping my laptop.

I ran ping 192.168.178.21 (laptop)
and tracert 192.168.178.21

relevant ipconfig /all from desktop pc (sorry for it being german):

```
Windows-IP-Konfiguration

   Hostname  . . . . . . . . . . . . : My-PC  
   Primäres DNS-Suffix . . . . . . . :  
   Knotentyp . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid  
   IP-Routing aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein  
   WINS-Proxy aktiviert  . . . . . . : Nein  
   DNS-Suffixsuchliste . . . . . . . : fritz.box  
Ethernet-Adapter Tunngle:  
   Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt  
   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:  
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : TAP-Win32 Adapter V9 (Tunngle)  
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : ----  
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja  
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja  

Ethernet-Adapter LAN-Verbindung:

   Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: fritz.box  
   Beschreibung. . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller  
   Physikalische Adresse . . . . . . : ----  
   DHCP aktiviert. . . . . . . . . . : Ja  
   Autokonfiguration aktiviert . . . : Ja  
   IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . . . . . . :  
   Temporäre IPv6-Adresse. . . . . . :  
   Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . :   
   IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.22(Bevorzugt)  
   Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0  
   Lease erhalten. . . . . . . . . . : Mittwoch, 24. August 2016 19:39:15  
   Lease läuft ab. . . . . . . . . . : Samstag, 3. September 2016 19:39:14  
   Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1  
   DHCP-Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.178.1  
   DHCPv6-IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 248012800  
   DHCPv6-Client-DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-BD-5B-27-C8-60-00-05-4E-71  

   DNS-Server  . . . . . . . . . . . : 
                                       192.168.178.1  
   NetBIOS über TCP/IP . . . . . . . : Aktiviert
```

Comment: What exactly is your question. The ip address appears to be connected to your ISP in some capacity

Comment: @Ramhound read the question "a cannot ping b. b however can ping a."

Comment: @ftp.x32 please list the IP addresses of each computer and the tracert command you used to obtain that result. It looks like whatever command you used went out onto the internet. If that IP is a piece of equipment owned by your ISP it's possible it's configured to not respond to pings

Comment: I have read the question you have submitted several times.  I see a statement that "Computer A cannot ping Computer B" but you have not asked a question.  So I will ask again, what is your question, specifically?  You should edit your question so, your question, is clear.

Comment: @nijave Updated original post

Comment: Please also add the ipconfig for the second machine. Since you're in your LAN, ping shouldn't get out through your GW. Also verify again your firewall on the Win 8 machine as Windows has a bad habit of enabling it automatically.

Comment: @Doezer I wouldn't say "bad" habit of enabling the firewall automatically, but it's not uncommon for it to aggressively block things. This can happen especially if you've connected to a network that's private/home but selected "Public" when Windows asked you about the network. Windows adjusts firewall settings based on whether you click "Public", "Work/Business", or "Home" network

Comment: I know, I didn't develop on purpose. Still, if you deactivate the firewall once, you don't want it to reactivate on his own without warning.